# How do I count the frequency against a specific list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this.

```
                date name
0 2015-06-13 00:21:25    a
1 2015-06-13 01:00:25    b
2 2015-06-13 02:54:48    c
3 2015-06-15 14:38:15    a
4 2015-06-15 15:29:28    b
```

I want to count the occurrences of dates against a specific date range, including ones that do not appear in the column (and ignores whatever that is in the `name` column). For example, I might have a date range that looks like this:

```
periods = pd.date_range('2015-06-13', '2015-06-16', freq = 'd')
```

Then, I want an output that looks something like:

```
date       count    
2015-06-13 3
2015-06-14 0
2015-06-15 2
2015-06-16 0
```

I haven't been able to find any function that let me keep the `0` rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first use [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) from column `date` for [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by `periods` with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `0`. Last convert `float` to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df['date'].dt.date.value_counts()
print df
2015-06-13    3
2015-06-15    2
Name: date, dtype: int64

periods = pd.date_range('2015-06-13', '2015-06-16', freq = 'd')

df = df.reindex(periods).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
df.columns = ['date','count']
print df
        date  count
0 2015-06-13      3
1 2015-06-14      0
2 2015-06-15      2
3 2015-06-16      0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the solution of @jezrael, but uses a groupby instead of value_counts:

```
>>> (pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.date.dt.date)['name']
                    .count()
                    .reindex(periods)
                    .fillna(0))
     .rename(columns={'name': 'count'}))
            count
2015-06-13      3
2015-06-14      0
2015-06-15      2
2015-06-16      0
```

Note:  In Pandas 0.18.0 the reindex operation changes the type of count from ints to floats, so if you are using that version you'll need to tack on `.astype(int)` to the end.

Comment: I try your solution and I have `float` values instaed of `int`. Why? Because `python 2.7.10`? Or because `NaN` in column? Or something else? What do you think? My solution return `float` too. Interesting.

Comment: I am running pandas 0.17.1 and Python 2.7.11.

Comment: Hmmmm, I use `pandas` `0.18.0`. Maybe there is difference. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I just tested in Pandas 1.18.0 and got floats as well after I reindexed.